# mergeAll not working the same as a lettable operator (rxjs 5.5+)?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs-lettable-operators

Before lettable operators, the code looked like this:

```
get someData$(): Observable<Data> {
  return this.dataService.higherOrderDataStream
    .mergeAll()
    .map(...);
}
```

Refactoring to use `pipe`, I get a type error essentially saying `Observable<Observable<Data>>` is not assignable to type `Observable<Data>`:

```
get someData$(): Observable<Data> {
  return this.dataService.higherOrderDataStream
    .pipe(
      mergeAll(),
      map(...)
    );
}
```

But the following works just fine (I assume one shouldn't mix lettable and chained operators):

```
get someData$(): Observable<Data> {
  return this.dataService.higherOrderDataStream
    .mergeAll()
    .pipe(
      map(...)
    );
}
```

Is there a different `mergeAll` I should be using? I'm using the one from `rxjs/operators` where I was using `rxjs/add/operator/mergeAll` previously. I thought these two implementations would be equivalent.

**Is this a bug or am I using the new `mergeAll` incorrectly?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in RxJS 5.5 with `mergeAll` and `concatAll`. It'll be fixed in RxJS 6.

For more details see: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2759

Fix was merged few days ago: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/3321

For now it's better to use `mergeMap(o => o)` or `concatMap(o => o)` instead.

Comment: Whew. Thanks for the info and links (upvoted). Going to try this in my code now and will accept if it works.

Comment: Works like a charm.